# Как выделить запятыми вводные слова?

Tags: пунктуация

Есть правило, согласно которому вводные слова могут обособляться вместе с оборотами. Но я не могу точно понять, когда и как его применять?

Примеры:

1. Не помню точно, сколько же человек в тот день пришло на собрание: 15 или 16 ? Скорее всего, 15 .
2. Наконец-то Николай получил работу, наверное, даже неплохую.
3. Наконец-то Николай получил работу и, наверное, неплохую.
4. Наконец-то Николай получил работу, наверное, неплохую.

Answer (score 2):

1) Не помню точно, сколько же человек в тот день пришло на собрание: 15 или 16 ? Скорее всего, 15 .

2) Наконец-то Николай получил работу -  даже неплохую, наверное.

3) Наконец-то Николай получил работу,  и наверное неплохую.

Пояснение

1) Вводные слова в начале обособленного оборота вполняют роль присоединительных союзов, в этом случае они обособляются вместе с пояснительным или присоединительным оборотом.

В остальных случаях, в том числе внутри обособленного оборота, вводные слова выделяются запятыми.

2)  В ряде предложений исправлен стиль ("проблемы" с тоническими ударениями и равновесными конструкциями).

Comment: я чувствую, что ваши исправления улучшают стиль, но мне хотелось бы лучше понять, как это работает. Где можно почитать про эти тонические ударения и равновесные конструкции?

Comment: а не филолог сможет в этом разобраться, или тяжеловато будет?

Comment: Увы, нигде. Теорию интонации изучают в высшей школе, но на практике она не применяется. Вернее, начинает применяться, но только в грамматике (в некоторых современных учебниках), но не в орфографии. Поэтому фразовые ударения, равновесие фразы носители языка чувствуют интуитивно. Вот, к примеру, порядок слов в предложении может быть разным, он выражает разные оттенки смысла, но каждый раз мы выбираем его по интуиции.

Comment: Надо бы ещё в орфографии применялись... Им и в пунктуации-то не место, этим тоническим ударениям с равновесными конструкциями.

Comment: Ну да, во всём должна быть первозданная, детская простота, мудрствовать не надо, не правда ли?  На эту тему я как раз прочитала интересную статью, вот некоторые цитаты из нее о том, какие тексты надо теперь писать."Нужно использовать слова только из повседневного словаря, желательно не больше 3-4 слогов. Самую важную информацию - на первый план, так как читатель вряд ли доберется до конца. Не надо применять синонимы - например, машины не следует называть автомобилями". И т.д.

Comment: Всё это признаки страшной и ужасной болезни, которая называется функциональной  безграмотностью, когда люди умеют читать, но не понимают прочитанного, узнают слова, но не могут их декодировать.  Болезнь  надвигается на нас с Запада, там она появилась в 80-х годах прошлого века  как реакция общества на переход в новую информационную среду.  Первые симптомы - это боязнь и неприятие научных слов и различных терминов.   В России в 2003 году достаточными навыками чтения обладали только 36% школьников.(Из статьи "Поговорим о функциональной неграмотности").

Comment: Вера, а вот не надо утрировать. Детская простота – это одно, а так называемое "равновесие фразы", да ещё влияние этого мифического "равновесия" на пунктуацию – са-авсем другое. А функциональная неграмотность тут вообще ни при чем.

Comment: Не надо призывать к простоте, мир и так устремился к примитивизму (наверное, защитная реакция от избытка  информации). Одно явление можно описать  разными способами, применяя разные модели. Вы же пытаетесь их отрицать, называете мифическими.Правильна та идея, которая работает на результат. Я же не призываю вас пользоваться интонацией, но почему-то вы считаете своим долгом негативно высказываться об этом  методе.